# angular-cli is injecting css files thar are not mentioned in angular-cli.json

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When executing ng-serve I realise that angular-cli is injecting many css, js files that I don't need ? How to have control over angular-cli js and css injection ?

angular-cli.json config

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "2.7.0",
    "name": "cip_front"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
  "assets",
  "favicon.ico"
],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
        "../node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css",
        "../node_modules/ladda/dist/ladda-themeless.min.css",
        "assets/styles/styles.css",
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/metismenu/dist/metisMenu.js",
        "../src/vendor/pace/pace.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
        "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [
  ],
  "packages": [
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

an example of a file that is injected and not mentioned is scss style for [ng2-smart-table](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table)

Comment: Can I see the files that you considered as not needed?
Having a control as in how to add libraries and links in an angular-cli project?

Comment: Make sure your question is clear and addressing the problem. This is ambiguous.

Comment: I have edited the queston to have more details

Comment: According to the example that you provided, you might be importing some modules of 'ng2-smart-table'. So that it injects the style of it automatically. You don't have to add it to the styles[] of cli.json
Is that what you have been facing?

Comment: yes that is the exact source of the problem. any solutions cleaner than forking the repo and commenting css files ?

Comment: If you're using 'ng2-smart table' it injects its styles. If the module is not used remove it simply. Have you identified the css files that are not needed for sure?
I am sorry that I don't know any ways to remove the css files. There might be a way or not

Comment: I need the module but I don't need css files. and yes I have identified the css files but not the way to remove it without impacting the deployement process